# How to set IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF for all connection in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am aware that I can turn off IDENTITY_INSERT for the current connection using the following command

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON
```

But I want to set it on for all connection for 10 minutes and then I want to turn it back off.

Is this possible? if so how can I do this?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by turning IDENTITY_INSERT table OFF for everyone? If it is to do a bulk insert, try have a look at the bulk insert command, it may be what you need here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: The only way I know of is using Sql Server Agent. Basically you would create a job...

Comment: You can create the job from a script. When the stored procedure runs you can get rid of it and such...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to execute SQL Command to turn it off

Comment: @LordBaconPants I am trying to do bulk insert using Laravel. but I think Laravel has some bug when doing this. I tried to set the Identity_insert to OF but for some reason it does not work. so I need to turn it off while the script run to populate the tables. One way I can do it is by changing the column type.

Comment: @MikeA That may be your best bet. I'm not aware, and honestly would be surprised if you could, switch off identity inserts for an entire database. 

You can reset the set on an identity column using https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx if it helps!